# error: cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined in ionic 4 and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am trying to build an app with ionic 4 and firebase. There are two types of users: simple users and admins. As an admin, I want to see on map where the users are, but only in a certain area. I was able to display my position on map and to update the marker with watchPosition(). I added some locations in my database for the simple users to see if i can access them and then display them on map. Everything worked well, the markers were displayed on map, but now i got this error: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined, but i didn't change anything in my code (where i accessed the locations of users) It's strange because a few days ago it worked well, and it worked on android too. 
Is this a problem from firebase or from geolocation, anyone have an idea?

This is my code:

```
 getMarkers() {

let usersLocations =[];
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .get()
  .then(userProfileSnapshot => {
      userProfileSnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().isAdmin==false)
        usersLocations.push(doc.data());
      });
  }).then((x) => {
    if(this.isAdmin==true)
    for(let i=0; i<usersLocations.length; i++) {
      let userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(usersLocations[i].Location.latitude, usersLocations[i].Location.longitude);
      let userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userPosition,
        icon: {
          url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
        },
        map: this.map
      });

  //     if(this.haversine_distance(this.locationMarker, userMarker)>1)
  //       userMarker.setVisible(false);
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we can say from the code you shared is that for some value of `i`, `usersLocations[i]` does not have a `Location` property. If you didn't change your code, you'll want to check which document is missing that property.

Alternatively, you can skip such documents and log their ID by changing the second `then` to:

```
for(let i=0; i<usersLocations.length; i++) {
  if (!usersLocations[i] || !usersLocations[i].Location) {
    console.error("Missing Location data in "+i+": "+JSON.stringify(usersLocations[i]));
    continue; // skip further processing of this user
  }
  let userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(usersLocations[i].Location.latitude, usersLocations[i].Location.longitude);
  let userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userPosition,
    icon: {
      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
    },
    map: this.map
  });
}
```

---

A slightly more modern/idiomatic way of accomplishing this is:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    // Convert the snapshot to an array of IDs and data
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { doc.id, ...doc.data() });
  })
  .then(documents => {
    // Remove admins
    return documents.filter(doc => doc.isAdmin==false);
  })
  .then(documents => {
    // Remove and log documents that have no location field
    return documents.filter(doc => {
      if (!doc.Location) {
        console.error(`Document ${doc.id} doesn't have a Location`);
        return false; // remove this document from the array
      }
      return true;
    });
  .then(documents => {
    documents.forEach(doc => {
      let userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(doc.Location.latitude, doc.Location.longitude);
      let userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userPosition,
        icon: {
          url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
        },
        map: this.map
      });
    });
  });
```